# How to multiply a tuple or a list of integers with a factor in Scala

Tags: scala, arraylist, tuples, operators

In Scala 2 I have a tuple like this:

```
val direction = (2,3)
```

This value `direction` I want to multiply with a `Int` factor `f` in order to get a new tuple

```
(2 * f, 3 * f)
```

So if `f=4` I looking for the result `(8,12)`.

I tried the obvious candidate `*`:

```
(2,3) * f
```

but `*` doesn't seem to be designed for these types.

Comment: Well, you show the answer right there: `(2 * f, 3 * f)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also `TupleN` has `productIterator`:

```scala
(1,2,3,4,5)
  .productIterator
  .map { case n: Int => n * 2 }
  .toList
```

This doesn't return another tuple but gives you easy iteration through all elements without adding any new libraries.

`productIterator` returns `Iterator[Any]` so you gotta use pattern matching.

Comment: Pretty verbose, but it does the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
// FUNCTION
object TupleProduct extends App {

  implicit class TupleProduct(tuple2: (Int, Int)) {
    def * : Int => (Int, Int) = (f: Int) => {
      (tuple2._1 * f, tuple2._2 * f)
    }
  }

  val direction = (2, 3)

  print(direction * 4)
}

// METHOD
object TupleProduct extends App {

  implicit class TupleProduct(tuple2: (Int, Int)) {
    def *(f: Int):(Int, Int) = {
      (tuple2._1 * f, tuple2._2 * f)
    }
  }

  val direction = (2, 3)

  print(direction * 4)
}
```

Comment: Why using a `Function` instead of a `Method`?

Comment: No particular reason, I don't know pros and cons of Function and Method @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Comment: Is not common to use `Functions` like that.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez can you please suggest some readings on it?

Comment: Not really, it is simply not common to prefer functions over methods in general. function are used as arguments for HOF or when you know you really want to use it as a function _(like calling `andThen` on it)_. Also, functions are more limited compared to methods. Maybe this helps: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/index.html#whats-the-difference-between-methods-and-functions